# Javascript async error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I add `async="async"` attribute to my script code as you see on image

for example:

```
<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="js/plugin.js"></script>
<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

[image]

and after added `javascript errors notifier` plugin gave me this error

[image]

and my error line code

[image]

```
$(function() {
 $(".lazy").lazy();
});
```

how can I fix it now

Comment: did you try this <script async type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: with `async` your scripts now loading in random sequence. your script trying to run some function that not loaded yet. so **remove async** back and enjoy

Comment: lesson: don't use features you don't fully understand

Comment: actually it works as async="async" but it doesn't always same error it just give sometimes interesting

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of "async". It lets the browser load the scripts at the same time and run them whenever they're ready. You get a different error depending on which script happens to load first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `defer` to defer the loading of the scripts.
2. Don't use `async="async"`: it means you are fine with it loading and executing at later time. The smaller scripts will be loaded and executed first.
3. You don't need to use `type="text/javascript"`. JavaScript has won.

So your code becomes:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/plugin.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
```

This should solve your problem.

---

Refer MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

> Async
>
> Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser should,
> if possible, execute the script asynchronously. It has no effect on
> inline scripts (i.e., scripts that don't have the src attribute)
>
> Defer
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded. The defer attribute shouldn't be used on scripts that don't have the src attribute.

Comment: thanks but now images is not appears I guess jquery lazy function doesn't work

Comment: I think that's a different question: Why's lazy not working? I'd suggest taking half an hour and reading up on lazy on jquery website and looking at some examples. I am sure you'll get it.

Comment: thanks a lot and I have another question is there any control statement in js to control it ? I mean if loaded do this..